# layout issue with different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-plus

I have a website, that works totally fine with FireFox (both desktop and android versions). but when I switch to another browser, the problems keep popping. check my homepage:

http://pichak-gallery.com

the header is well placed in firefox, but when you open the page in chrome,the header is not at its place. so I have to add this:

```
margin-top:-16px
```

[image]

but this will break the website in firefox. I don't even say that website is totally broken in IE.

another problem belongs to Google+1 button. that doesnt show up in chrome,until you press F12 and open inspect elements, then the button will show itself.

for example in this page:

http://pichak-gallery.com/index.php/7-maincategory/5-gallery.html

this will happen:

[image]

I worked on the codes for a long time, to investigate the problem. but I can't find any problem in the codes.

Have anyone else experienced these? Is there a code or script to be able to fix these?

Comment: can you read my post here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338858/dynamic-website-width/25339189#25339189

Comment: tnx for the post. i will need it in future for my responsive design. but i don't think this has to do anything with this problem... the problem should be from some extra-unnecessary codes,or some difference between user agents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok now i got it.

the 1st problem was because of a few lines from java template. starting with :

```
﻿<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
?>
```

as far as i know these lines are for some security reasons, and i didnt think they will have any effect on layout since they dont echo anything.

the 2nd problem was about the custom line i added into my css. i manually overrided the original styles of google+1 button with !important tags, which it made problem with some browser. i had to put g+1 button in a DIV, then add those style to the mentioned DIV.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed while viewing page source in FF is that you have an incorrect `script` tag as shown here (in red), between `head` and `body` tags.

[image: FF]

So, I'm guessing that's the problem why you're getting this kind of rendering layout in Chrome

[image: Chrome]

All your `link` and `script` tags somehow get inside `body`, and you have `empty` "div". The moment I deleted that node in the inspector, the problem disappeared. So, try erasing that `<script type="text/javascript"> ; </script>` or move it inside `head`.

Comment: tnx for the time you spent on this. but what exactly did you delete? i almost deleted the whole nodes on the page,and nothing happened. and i cant find that empty div... must be generated by a java script.

Comment: Check the 2nd image (that empty space marked in blue in inspector). I'm guessing it got generated that way because of the incorrect `script` tag that is shown in image 1 (marked in red).

Comment: i totally deleted that script... but there is still an empty "" that can not even be deleted. you can check the website again... to see it has been removed.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see any more flaws regarding html/css. Are you creating/inserting some elements via JS? Can you show us JS code? I'm positively sure that this is a user, not browser error.

Comment: well im not using any other codes than you see in page source. however,i tried to remove every single elements, except header,body and main div. and i still had the same issue... only 2 elements and couldnt style it correctly XD!! weird.

Comment: It's got to be one of the plugins you use or one of your own JS files, currently can't help you more than this, sorry.

Comment: I agree with @Davion, all scripts have to get moved from <body> to <head> section to get the problem fixed.

Comment: no problem dude. i found out the 2nd problem's solution (g+1 not showing up). it was because of my slide show script( the one with the text) so i had to click on NEXT to make g+1 show up. currently i'm stuck with the layout.... tnx for the time anyway :)

Comment: @emmanuel i understand that i need to move scripts into head tag, but some instruction insist that the script should be included in body... or it won't work.

Comment: That's true, but once I have checked that before there were too many. You have to keep in body only ones that instructed from constructor to be there.